# How to return the results form a DatePickerFragment to a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker

How to return the results from a `DatePicker` to the Fragment that called it.

I would like to display a Toast with the results of the `DatePicker` in from the Fragment that called it.

```
public class UIFragment extends Fragment  {

    @BindView(R.id.btn_date_picker) Button btnDatePicker;

     @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ui, container, false);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreateView");

        // ButterKnife
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        btnDatePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Date Picker");


                // A DialogFragment displays a dialog window floating on top of the activity window.
                DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

            }
        });

        public void processDatePickerResult(int year, int month, int day) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "processDatePickerResult()");

        String month_string = Integer.toString(month + 1);
        String day_string = Integer.toString(day);
        String year_string = Integer.toString(year);
        String date = (month_string + "/" + day_string + "/" + year_string);

        displayToast(date);
    }

}
```

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener  {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = DatePickerFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener;


    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDateSet: Year: " + year + " month: " + (month + 1) + " Day: " + dayOfMonth);

        UIFragment uiFragment = (UIFragment)getTargetFragment();
        uiFragment.processDatePickerResult(year, month, dayOfMonth);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreateDialog");

        // Use current date as the default date in the picker.
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it.
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);

    }

}
```

The APP crashes after the `DatePickerFragment.onDateSet` Method and, `UIFragment.processDatePickerResult` method.

**I've included a copy of Log cat:**

> 2019-07-25 21:26:18.867 14671-14671/com.example.androidui2
>   D/UIFragment: onCreateView 2019-07-25 21:26:24.425
>   14671-14671/com.example.androidui2 D/UIFragment: Date Picker
>   2019-07-25 21:26:24.444 14671-14671/com.example.androidui2
>   D/DatePickerFragment: onCreateDialog 2019-07-25 21:26:26.701
>   14671-14671/com.example.androidui2 D/DatePickerFragment: onDateSet:
>   Year: 2019 month: 7 Day: 25 2019-07-25 21:26:26.705
>   14671-14671/com.example.androidui2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>       Process: com.example.androidui2, PID: 14671
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.example.androidui2.FragmentTabs.UIFragment.processDatePickerResult(int,
>   int, int)' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.androidui2.Picker.DatePickerFragment.onDateSet(DatePickerFragment.java:50)
>           at android.app.DatePickerDialog.onClick(DatePickerDialog.java:171)
>           at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:172)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Comment: You can easily implement this with event bus this link should help https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code.

UIFragment.java

```
public class UIFragment extends Fragment implements DatePickerFragment.IDateSetListener  {

    @BindView(R.id.btn_date_picker) Button btnDatePicker;

     @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ui, container, false);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreateView");

        // ButterKnife
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        final DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        ((DatePickerFragment)newFragment).setIDateSetListener(this);

        btnDatePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Date Picker");


                // A DialogFragment displays a dialog window floating on top of the activity window.        

              newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void processDatePickerResult(int year, int month, int day) {

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "processDatePickerResult()");

        String month_string = Integer.toString(month + 1);
        String day_string = Integer.toString(day);
        String year_string = Integer.toString(year);
        String date = (month_string + "/" + day_string + "/" + year_string);

        displayToast(date);
    }

}
```

DatePickerFragment.java

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener  {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = DatePickerFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    IDateSetListener dateSetListener;

    public void setIDateSetListener(IDateSetListener listener) {
        dateSetListener = listener;
    }

    public interface IDateSetListener {
        void processDatePickerResult(int year, int month, int day)
    }


    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDateSet: Year: " + year + " month: " + (month + 1) + " Day: " + dayOfMonth);
        if (dateSetListener != null) {
            dateSetListener.processDatePickerResult(year, month, dayOfMonth);
        }
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreateDialog");

        // Use current date as the default date in the picker.
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it.
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);

    }

}
```

Comment: This works but some things are unclear to me. 
Why does the DialogFragment have to be declared outside of the onClickListner()? 
The date Fragment has two warnings in it. 
1) DatePickerFragment should provide a constructor with no arguments.
2) Avoid non-default constructors in fragments: use a default constructor plus Fragment#setArguments?.

Comment: This implementation uses interface to communicate between your dialog fragment and UIFragment. So in-order to pass the instance of UIFragment(which implemented the interface `IDateSetListener`) to DatePickerFragment I moved the `DialogFragment` to outside.

Comment: I made the code using notepad++. I don't have access to an IDE now. You can use setter methods instead of passing in constructor. I will update the answer.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: Cool, this works like a charm I have some digging to do on Listeners but its what I needed. Thanks